# Not getting full path of NSLibraryDirectory

Tags: iphone, directory

I want to get images from a folder that is located in `NSLibraryDirectory`.

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:str]];

 NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [@"images" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]] stringByAppendingFormat:@".png"];
 img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
 NSLog(@"img:%@", img);
```

This is the code i am using in which

Printing description of getImagePath:

> /Users/Admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/6842528E-9629-4DE7-96C1-A46AEB8A8EE0/Library/Thapa

It should be:

Printing description of getImagePath:

> /Users/Admin/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/6842528E-9629-4DE7-96C1-A46AEB8A8EE0/Library/Thapa/images47.png

How to achieve this don't know, what i tried is above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're doing far too much stuff within one line of code.  And the best practice for writing code is to keep things simple (so your code is readable to you and anyone else who looks at it).

When I look at this line:

```
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [@"images" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]] stringByAppendingFormat:@".png"];
```

There's just too much going on there!

Why not do something like:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if(paths)
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:str]];
    if(documentsDirectory)
    {
        NSInteger highScoreNumber = [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults] integerForKey: @"HighScore"];
        NSString * numberGraphicFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"images%d.png", highScoreNumber ];
        if(numberGraphicFilename)
        {
            NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: numberGraphicFilename];
            if(getImagePath)
            {
                img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bonus: This also introduces the concept of error checking / handling to your code.

It's more code to write, but it's a lot easier to read and follow along.  And you might be able to isolate what the problem really is by going this route.

Comment: It seems more meaningfull way,let me try it first.

Comment: I got my problem, why image is not getting because userdefault instead of getting value it is incrementing the counter, but why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

Change the **getImagePath** as

```
NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [@"YourSubFolderName/images" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]] stringByAppendingFormat:@".png"];
```

**So your code will look like below**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [@"YourSubFolderName/images" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]] stringByAppendingFormat:@".png"];
img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
NSLog(@"img:%@", img);
```

Comment: I got my problem, why image is not getting because userdefault instead of getting value it is incrementing the counter, but why it is so?

Comment: the above code will retrieve only last save d image. What r u trying to do.Please explain

Comment: ya, i am trying to fetch all images of a particular folder in a array.

Comment: values of NSUserDefaults starts from 1,2,3 etc... am i right ?

Comment: then loop it, start from 1 and end to NSUserDefaults value

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18861/discussion-between-ramshad-and-apple-delegates)

Comment: sure, but let it be tomorrow.